# How to iterate through repeated dataset to get monthly totals?

Tags: r, count, counter

How would I iterate through a data frame in R to get total quantity for each variable based on dates (of arbitrary order and quantity)?

```
Date          Var
2019-03-1    A    
2019-01-1    A
2019-03-1    B
2019-02-1    A
2019-01-1    A
2019-01-1    B
2019-02-1    A
2019-02-1    A
2019-02-1    B
2019-01-1    A
2019-03-1    C
```

To populate another frame that contains

```
Date         Var A          Var B            Var C
2019-01-1    3              1                0
2019-02-1    3              1                0
2019-03-1    1              1                1
```

Comment: What did you tried ? where did you get stuck on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the `count` of 'Date', 'Var' and reshape from 'long' to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #1.0.0
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   count(Date, Var = str_c('Var_', Var)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Var, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Date      Var_A Var_B Var_C
#  <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 2019-01-1     3     1     0
#2 2019-02-1     3     1     0
#3 2019-03-1     1     1     1
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `table`

```
table(df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2019-03-1", "2019-01-1", "2019-03-1", 
"2019-02-1", "2019-01-1", "2019-01-1", "2019-02-1", "2019-02-1", 
"2019-02-1", "2019-01-1", "2019-03-1"), Var = c("A", "A", "B", 
"A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple oneliner in data.table

```
library(data.table)
dcast( DT, Date ~ Var)

#         Date A B C
# 1: 2019-01-1 3 1 0
# 2: 2019-02-1 3 1 0
# 3: 2019-03-1 1 1 1
```

**sample data**

```
DT <- data.table::fread("Date          Var
2019-03-1    A    
2019-01-1    A
2019-03-1    B
2019-02-1    A
2019-01-1    A
2019-01-1    B
2019-02-1    A
2019-02-1    A
2019-02-1    B
2019-01-1    A
2019-03-1    C")
```